# Does Xcode-Maven-Plugin can build iOS app on PC

Tags: ios, xcode, maven

I created a pom file for building iOS app. It can successfully build an iOS app on Mac. I searched online and I couldn't find a way to build the same pom file on PC. I just wanted to be sure that if it's possible to build the app on PC. I read that PhoneGap apps for iOS can be built on PC. So I thought it may possible to build my app on PC. Please bear with me if it's a silly question but unfortunately I couldn't find an obvious answer for that. Here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.package</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyAppName</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>xcode-app</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios</groupId>
             <artifactId>xcode-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.14.0</version>
             <extensions>true</extensions>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                   <id>package-xcode-project</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                      <goal>package-xcodeproj</goal>
                   </goals>
                </execution>
             </executions>  
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, X-Code is only fully available on the Mac (OS-X), there exists no complete and supported environment on the PC.
So you should not try to build an environment there, furthermore the Maven plugin is only a build tool for combining and using available tools and adds version resolution mechanics to your build process and is not responsible for the compilers themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. As I mentioned I just wanted to make sure that it's impossible to build on PC. Thanks for your complete explanation. I'll mark it as an accepted answer in 48 hours.